# dynamic object name

Tags: c#, .net, for-loop

To minimize this code using a loop?

```
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn combo_1 = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
string name_1 = "name_1";
string name1 = "Name 1";
combo_1.Name = name_1;
combo_1.HeaderText = name1;

DataGridViewComboBoxColumn combo_2 = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
string name_2 = "name_2";
string name2 = "Name 2";
combo_2.Name = nazwa_2;
combo_2.HeaderText = nazwa2;

DataGridViewComboBoxColumn combo_3 = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
string name_3 = "name_3";
string name3 = "Name_3";
combo_3.Name = name_3;
combo_3.HeaderText = name3;

DataGridViewComboBoxColumn combo_4 = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
string nazwa_4 = "name_4";
string nazwa4 = "Name 4";
combo_4.Name = name_4;
combo_4.HeaderText = name4;
```

Sorry for not clear question, I will try to explain...
I want to add table in to datagridview1

```
// define combobox column
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn combo_1 = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
string name_1 = "name_1";
string name1 = "Name 1";
combo_1.Name = name_1;
combo_1.HeaderText = name1;

// set value to combobox column
pol.Open();
string list_value = "SELECT value FROM table ORDER BY name ASC";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(list_value, conn); //conn is defined above in code
SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (rdr.Read())
{
string name = rdr.GetString(0);
combo_1.Items.Add(name); / 
}
pol.Close();


// add all column
dataGridView1.Columns.Add("name_column_1", "Name");
dataGridView1.Columns.Add("name_column_2", "Forname");
int index = 2;
dataGridView1.Columns.Insert(index, combo_1);

//add value to cell
DataGridViewComboBoxCell cell = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[index];
cell.Value = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[index];
```

For "combo_2", "combo_3" etc. I would have to do a few of these fragments differing only in "_1"

If i can use for loop to add combo_1, combo_2, combo_3

```
//define combobox
DataGridViewComboBoxColumn combo = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
for (int i = 1; i <= number_column; i++)
{
string name_1 = "name_" + i;
string name1 = "Name " + i;
combo_1.Name = name_1;
combo_1.HeaderText = name1;
}
//add column
for (int i = 1; i <= liczba_kolumn; i++)
{
int nr = 2;
dataGridView1.Columns.Insert(nr, combo);
nr= nr + 1;
}
//set value
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[0];
dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[1];

for (int j = 1; j <= number_column; j++)
{
int nr = 2;
DataGridViewComboBoxCell cell = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[nr];
cell.Value = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[nr];
nr = nr + 1;
}
}
```

error: Additional information: The specified column already belongs to a DataGridView control.
I know why this error is, but i do not know how to change combo name dynamicly.

Comment: Please try to edit, this doesn't make much sense... Where does `combo` come from...? Do you realize that everytime you use `index` it has the same value `2`?

Comment: C# has arrays, dictionaries etc. use them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the question, but I'll take a stab at it...
Let's start with the error you have:

> error: Additional information: The specified column already belongs to
> a DataGridView control.

I suspect this is because of these 2 lines:

```
int index = 2;
dataGridView1.Columns.Insert(index, combo);
```

Do you perhaps mean to use the "i" from your for loop? Or maybe you meant to declare `index` outside of the for loop (I see you are incrementing it below)?

```
dataGridView1.Columns.Insert(i, combo);
```

or

```
int index = 2;
for (int i = 1; i <= number_of_columns; i++)
{
    dataGridView1.Columns.Insert(index, combo);
    index = index + 1; // or this could be index++;
}
```

Now let's look at the title and first line of your question (which is a different topic):

> c# dynamic object name
>
> To minimize this code using a loop (or other)?

You could do something like

```
List<DataGridViewComboBoxColumn> myColumns = new List<DataGridViewComboBoxColumn>();
for(int i=0; i < (the number you want); i++)
{
     DataGridViewComboBoxColumn combo = new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn();
     combo.Name = "name_" + i;
     combo.HeaderText = "Name " + i;
}
```

This would give you a (somewhat) dynamic list of `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`.  However, if you are just going to add them right away, you may prefer:

```
for(int i=0; i < (the number you want); i++)
{
     dataGridView1.Columns.Insert(i, new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn{
                                      Name = "name_" + i,
                                      HeaderText = "Name " + i});
}
```

I haven't checked that for syntax, but it should at least be close.

Is that what you were going for?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks PhatWrat, you helped me to solve the problem.

```
            pol.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter list_adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT value FROM box ORDER BY value ASC", pol);
        DataTable list_dt = new DataTable();
        list_adapter.Fill(list_dt);

        string[] items = new string[list_dt.Rows.Count];

        for (int i = 0; i < list_dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            items[i] = list_dt.Rows[i][0].ToString();
            //MessageBox.Show(list_dt.Rows[i][0].ToString());
        }
        pol.Close();

        int index = 2;
        for (int i = 1; i <= number_of_columns; i++)
        {
            dataGridView1.Columns.Insert(index, new DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
            {
                Name = "name_" + i,
                HeaderText = "Name " + i,
                DataSource = items
            });
            index = index + 1;
        }

            pol.Open();
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY name ASC", pol);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        adapter.Fill(dt);

        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add();
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[0];
            dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].Value = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[1];
            int index_2 = 2;
            for (int j = 1; j <= number_of_columns; j++)
            {
                DataGridViewComboBoxCell cell = (DataGridViewComboBoxCell)dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[index_2];
                cell.Value = dt.Rows[i].ItemArray[index_2];
                index_2 = index_2 + 1;
            }

        }
        pol.Close();
```